# Please Explain This Question About Predicates and Nested Quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need help solving/understanding this question:

L (x,y) : "x loves y".
Translate "there are exactly two people whom Lynn loves".
Its answer includes a variable "z". I do not get that part with the variable "z". How did it come here when it was not introduced in the question? Detailed solution is appreciated. Thanks!
P.S i do not know how to write the equation in the answer here.

Comment: Are you being asked to translate that statement in mathematical terms?

Comment: @browngreen yes

Comment: [To learn how to write](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are really trying to do is to say that there are two different things loved by Lynn, and any other thing isnl not. You can elaborate on this sentence like this:

"There exists some X and Y, for which: X is not Y [so that there are two different people], Lynn loves X, Lynn loves Y, and all Zs which are not X or Y are not loved by Lynn."

The predicate logic sentence will look like this:
$$
\exists x\exists y(\neg Equal(x, y) \wedge Loves(lynn, x) \wedge Loves(lynn, y) \wedge \forall z((\neg Equal(x, z) \wedge \neg Equal(y, z)) \rightarrow \neg Loves(lynn, z)))
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let’s take it one step at a time. How can we formalize *there is someone whom Lynn loves*? That’s fairly straightforward:

$$\exists x\,\big(L(\text{Lynn},x)\big)\;,$$

or in words, *there is an* $x$ *such that Lynn loves* $x$.

How about *there are (at least) two people whom Lynn loves*? For a first approximation we could try

$$\exists x\,\exists y\,\big(L(\text{Lynn},x)\land L(\text{Lynn},y)\big)\;,\tag{1}$$

but that doesn’t quite work. To see why it doesn’t work, suppose that Kerry is the only person whom Lynn loves; then we could let $x=\text{Kerry}$ and $y=\text{Kerry}$, and $(1)$ would be true, even thourh Lynn loves only one person. We need to add something to force $x$ and $y$ to be different people:

$$\exists x\,\exists y\,\big(x\ne y\land L(\text{Lynn},x)\land L(\text{Lynn},y)\big)\;.\tag{2}$$

That’s better: $(2)$ really does say that there are two *different* people whom Lynn loves. However, $(2)$ does not place any upper limit on the number of people whom Lynn loves: Lynn could love $2000$ people, and $(2)$ would still be true. If we want to say that Lynn loves *exactly* two people, we have to add something to $(2)$ that makes $x$ and $y$ stand for the only people whom Lynn loves. And this, I think, is where you’re running into trouble.

The idea is to add a clause that says that if $z$ stands for someone whom Lynn loves, then $z$ stands for one of the same people as $x$ and $y$. That is, there is no third person whom Lynn loves: if $x,y$, and $z$ represent three people who are loved by Lynn, then $z$ represents the same person as either $x$ or $y$. A first attempt might look like this:

$$\exists x\,\exists y\,\Big(x\ne y\land L(\text{Lynn},x)\land L(\text{Lynn},y)\land\big(L(\text{Lynn},z)\to(z=x\lor z=y)\big)\Big)\;.\tag{3}$$

The problem with $(3)$ is that $z$ is a free variable, so that $(3)$ is a formula (or, as it’s sometimes called in elementary treatments, an open sentence with an empty slot $z$ to be filled in), rather than an actual sentence. What we really want to say is that $(3)$ is true **no matter which person we fill in for the ‘hole’** $z$, i.e., that it’s true for **every** possible value of $z$:

$$\exists x\,\exists y\,\Big(x\ne y\land L(\text{Lynn},x)\land L(\text{Lynn},y)\land\color{red}{\forall z}\,\big(L(\text{Lynn},z)\to(z=x\lor z=y)\big)\Big)\;.$$

I put the $\forall z$ in what I think is the intuitively most natural place, but we can also move it to the front, right after the existential quantifiers:

$$\exists x\,\exists y\,\forall z\,\Big(x\ne y\land L(\text{Lynn},x)\land L(\text{Lynn},y)\land\big(L(\text{Lynn},z)\to(z=x\lor z=y)\big)\Big)\;.$$

In words:

> There are people $x$ and $y$ such that no matter who $z$ is, $x$ and $y$ are different people, and Lynn loves $x$, and Lynn loves $y$, and if Lynn loves $z$, then $z$ is one of these two special people $x$ and $y$.

A bit more informally:

> There are distinct people $x$ and $y$ such that no matter who $z$ may be, Lynn loves both $x$ and $y$, and if Lynn also loves $z$, then $z$ is one of $x$ and $y$.